# Getting incorrect rank using WHERE clause in mySQL

Tags: mysql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/083f5d/1

It's returning 6th rank instead of 1st rank in above SQL query. What changes I need to do in SQL query so it provides 1st rank because I have used WHERE condition to check mpkid and roundpkid (WHERE mpkid=37 AND roundpkid=3).

Here is the query:

```
SELECT mpkid, totalvote, rank 
FROM ( 
 SELECT mpkid, roundpkid, totalvote, 
 @n := IF(@g = totalvote, @n, @n + 1) rank, 
 @g := totalvote 
 FROM tr_msearch_vote_summary, 
 (SELECT @n := 0) i 
 ORDER BY totalvote DESC 
) q 
WHERE mpkid=37 AND roundpkid=3
```

What I want:

Please see sqlfiddle first. There is only one record for round #3, and it is 37 so I want that it should display rank #1 for mpkid #37 and round #3 but it is giving rank #6.

Comment: better to post query here

Comment: query posted in question, please have a look at it.

Comment: Question is not that much clear. What are your comparison parameters and what data you want?

Comment: @kamaldeep, I just edited my question and added more info on what result I want and what I am getting right now.

Comment: that's to be expected. your rank is being generated inside the sub-query, then you use the parent/outer query to filter those results - that means you lose any non-matching records, and get gaps in your rank value. you'd have to implement ranking in the outer query if you want consecutive 1,2,3,....-type numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this query,

```
SELECT mpkid, totalvote, rank 
FROM ( 
  SELECT mpkid, roundpkid, totalvote, 
  @n := IF(@g = totalvote, @n, @n + 1) rank, 
  @g := totalvote 
  FROM tr_msearch_vote_summary, 
  (SELECT @n := 0) i 
WHERE roundpkid=3
ORDER BY totalvote DESC 
) q 
WHERE mpkid=37
```

And here is your updated sqlfiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/083f5d/9

Comment: Ah ok, you want the rank per round.. got it. Please consider initialising @g however.

Comment: can you explain `@n := IF(@g = totalvote, @n, @n + 1) rank`  What does it mean? also `(SELECT @n := 0) i`

Comment: @kamaldeepsinghbhatia The first tracks the rank in the variable @n and adds 1 for each row (unless the total vote, tracked by @g, is the same as the row before).. the second initialises @n as 0 with a CROSS JOIN so that the addition is calculated correctly and any old value stored in @n is cleared.

Comment: @Arth In place of condition here we have given three comma separated values? I got confused here.

Comment: @kamaldeepsinghbhatia `IF(*condition is true*, *return this*, *else return this*)` or in this case..  if total vote is the same, keep rank the same, else increment rank by 1.

Answer (score 2):

You are applying the WHERE condition after the ranking is already complete. I'm guessing you want to do the ranking after the WHERE is applied:

```
  SELECT t.mpkid, t.roundpkid,  
         @n := IF(@g = t.totalvote, @n, @n + 1) rank,
         @g := t.totalvote totalvote
    FROM tr_msearch_vote_summary t, (SELECT @n := 0) i 
   WHERE t.mpkid=37 AND t.roundpkid=3
ORDER BY t.totalvote DESC
```

You should also initialise @g to make sure it isn't preset in another query:

```
  SELECT t.mpkid, t.roundpkid,  
         @n := IF(@g = t.totalvote, @n, @n + 1) rank,
         @g := t.totalvote totalvote
    FROM tr_msearch_vote_summary t, (SELECT @n := 0, @g := NULL) i 
   WHERE t.mpkid=37 AND t.roundpkid=3
ORDER BY t.totalvote DESC
```

**UPDATE**

If you want the ranking grouped by round and then to simply SELECT by mpkid, this is a more powerful query:

```
SELECT mpkid,
       roundpkid,
       totalvote,
       rank
  FROM (
    SELECT t.mpkid,  
           @n := CASE 
                   WHEN @r = t.roundpkid AND @g = t.totalvote THEN @n
                   WHEN @r = t.roundpkid THEN @n + 1
                   ELSE 1
                 END rank,
           @r := t.roundpkid roundpkid,
           @g := t.totalvote totalvote
      FROM tr_msearch_vote_summary t, (SELECT @n := 0, @g := NULL, @r := NULL) i 
  ORDER BY t.roundpkid, t.totalvote DESC
       ) r
 WHERE mpkid = 37;
```

Note that you do not need to supply the roundpkid. [See updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/083f5d/20)